# Axios Error with Status Code 415 in Using Get Method

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core-mvc, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

Good day,

I'm facing this error code using axios.get. The error code is 415. What I want to do is, supply const object to send it to my controller. I tried to debug the controller but it doesn't proceed in my controller (ASP.NET Core Controller).

Here are my sample codes:

```
// Class that I want to supply
public class User{
    public int? Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime? Bday {get;set;}
}

// My Controller
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers([FromBody] User user){
    // Do something here
}

// My js file axios is already imported and working
async searchUser(){
    const user = {
        Name: name,
        Bday: bday
    }

    await axios.get(`/SomePage/GetUsers/`,user).then(response=>{
        // do something here
    }.catch(error=>{console.log(error);});
}
```

I hope someone will help me find a solution about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The HTTP status code 415 means Unsupported Media Type. That is it indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415),

> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

Can you change your API action `FromBody` to `FromQuery`. Technically that should work.

Comment: Do you have sample fix?

Comment: Can you try `axios.get('endpoint', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})` .

Comment: oh oh, you are sending an complex object to a GET action. Can you post how your API endpoint looks like? Is it something like, `Get([FromUri]User user)`?

Comment: It is in my controller method.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't notice the controller code. Can you change your API action `FromBody` to `FromQuery`. Technically that should work

Comment: In the most recent WebApi the attribute is [FromUri]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Jaliya is right. You can also view this docs from Microsoft about Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API since you're dealing with API request. [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

pass header when calling axios

`axios.get("https://api.url.com", {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`